# Microsoft excel average excluding blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macbook

I am trying to get an average on a large sheet only including specific cells that are not consecutive and I want my average to exclude blank cells.  I have conditional formatting to highlight the cells that are less than zero, not sure if this is what is not allowing me to exclude the blank cells.

an example of what i want to average is cells F3,R3,AD3,AP3,BB3,BN3,BZ3,CL3,CX3,DJ3,DV3,EH3,ET3,FF3,FR3,GD3,GP3,HB3,HN3,IL3,IX3,JJ3

thanks,

Comment: The Excel `AVERAGE` function already excludes blanks from it's calculations.  Is it doing something unexpected when you tried this?

Comment: And unless you explicitly direct for it to in the writing of the formula, Conditional Formatting does not interfere with the running of a formula.

Comment: `AVERAGE` does not exclude zeroes. Are the fields you're trying to exclude actually blank/empty, or zeroes?

Answer (score 1):

Pick a cell and enter:

```
=AVERAGE(F3,R3,AD3,AP3,BB3,BN3,BZ3,CL3,CX3,DJ3,DV3,EH3,ET3,FF3,FR3,GD3,GP3,HB3,HN3,IL3,IX3,JJ3)
```

[image]

At least once cell in the range must contain a numeric value.